# Can we take join in Redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a sorted set, SortedSet1 = "token"=>"score"

I have a list, List1 = "token"=>"username"

Now, I want to have a record with JSON string value like-

e.g> "token"=>"{name:username, score: score}"

so that I can broadcast a leaderboard.

How to JOIN these two sets ? Or is there any chance to have JOIN of two lists or two sets ?

Comment: Or anything like merging of lists on same keys ?

Comment: where does `name` come into picture and also `List1` look like a `hash` rather then `list`

Answer (score 2):

redis is simply a key/value store. you cannot do something like sql-joins. you need to do that by yourself (use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs) for merging).

there is also something that is called LUA-scripting in redis. maybe that will work for you, but i have never worked with it, so i probably cannot help you there: http://redis.io/commands/eval

Comment: Thanks a lot for this confirmation that joins will not work here.

I am woring with node.js and also I am new to this javascript, then what should I pick from underscore.js and lodash ?

Comment: i would pick lodash, its a lot faster and has more functionality

Comment: Some key/value store DB support, at least partially, join operations. For example BerkeleyDB or RethinkDB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to doing Joins in Redis.
https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/5iz0gi/joins_in_redis/
The concept is to use sorted sets as indexes, then extracting and doing intersections on the scores.