# Can redis supports queries like sql join and group by while replacing sql DB with Redis?

Tags: sql, redis

I have a project in which i need to replace the SQL DB with REDIS. Its a job scheduling system. There are tables like JobInfo, TaskInfo, Result, BatchInfo etc. 
What is the best way to map DB tables in REDIS server key value pair?

There are join and group by kind of queries used in the project. 
What is the best way to replace the sql server with the redis server? Also does redis provides a way with which i can query the data like i can in join and group by queries?

Comment: No http://redis.io/topics/indexes

Comment: [RedisGraph](https://oss.redis.com/redisgraph/commands/), Yes

Answer (score 10):

Redis is basically a key-value store (a bit more sophisticated than just a simple one, but yet - a key-value db). the value may be a document that follows some schema, but Redis isn't optimized to search for those documents and query them like other Document Databases or like relational database such as SQL Server.

I dont know why you're trying to migrate from SQL Server to Redis, but you need to re-check yourself if that's the right design choice. If you need fixed schema and join operations - it may suggest that Redis isn't the right solution.

If all you're looking for is caching, you can cache in the application layer, or use other solution to integrate your Redis and SQL Server (I wrote simple open-source project that does that: http://redisql.ishahar.net ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: you could, however, use redisgraph

Answer (score 1):

I guess its not possible though you can see below post to implement JOIN like feature in Redis.

[Can we take join in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454538/can-we-take-join-in-redis)

Please refer below post as well:

[Redis database table desing like sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347437/redis-database-table-desing-like-sql)